# Upgrade Ambari Server failed with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: ambari, hdp

I'm upgrading ambari server version 2.6 to version 2.7, following this document

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.1.0/bk_ambari-upgrade-major/content/upgrade_ambari.html

The tasks work perfectly until step 12. When I run `ambari-server upgrade -v`, it produces this error:

```
    INFO: Loading properties from /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 1060, in <module>
    mainBody()
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 1030, in mainBody
    main(options, args, parser)
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 980, in main
    action_obj.execute()
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 79, in execute
    self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_server/serverUpgrade.py", line 262, in upgrade
    retcode = run_schema_upgrade(args)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_server/serverUpgrade.py", line 125, in run_schema_upgrade
    db_title = get_db_type(get_ambari_properties()).title
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your `/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties` properties file is damaged or maybe empty.